# Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss. -novice

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to do `mle` for school assignment, why could I be getting this error:

```
#1) Find best fitting distribution parameters
best_fit(macamil2data) 
#     {'loglaplace': {'c': 1.0603278885766216,
#                     'loc': -0.04671203840594998,
#                     'scale': 10.230045114772532}}

#2) Calculate pdf using said parameters
def loglaplace_loglikelihood(params, data):
    c, loc, scale = params
    return stats.loglaplace.logpdf(data, c=c, loc=loc, scale=scale).sum()

#3) Minimize using said parameters
initial_params = [1.0603278885766216, -0.04671203840594998, 10.230045114772532]
results = minimize(loglaplace_loglikelihood, initial_params, args=(macamil2data))

print(results)

 message: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
  success: False
   status: 2
      fun: nan
        x: [ 5.127e+03 -1.765e+05 -1.945e+03]
      nit: 2
      jac: [       nan        nan        nan]
 hess_inv: [[ 6.876e-01 -1.388e+01  5.195e-02]
            [-1.388e+01  5.437e+02  5.473e+00]
            [ 5.195e-02  5.473e+00  1.000e+00]]
     nfev: 464
     njev: 116
```

Tried lowering `gtol`, but it appears to me that I am making a systematic error my first time working with data in py. Sorry if it;s silly.

```
macamil2data=
0.916666
1
3.3
3.38333
3.68333
4.16667
4.2
6.08333
6.61667
7.03333
7.5
7.85
8.15
9.08333
9.35
10.0833
10.1833
10.4333
11.2833
14.2
16.5333
20.0333
23.8333
30.35
30.5167
32.4667
37.1
40.8167
45.6
52
70.0667
70.5333
85.2333
130.967
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a negative sign in your objective function. You want to maximize the log likelihood, so minimize the negative log likelihood. (Next time, please include a complete but minimal reproducible example, including the required imports.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

- A missing minus sign in your likelihood function as you want to minimize it;
- Probably not enough data to ensure proper convergence for this long tailed distribution.

For the parameters you provided, it seems at least a thousand points are needed.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats, optimize

p = [1.0603278885766216, -0.04671203840594998, 10.230045114772532]
X = stats.loglaplace(c=p[0], loc=p[1], scale=p[2])

np.random.seed(123456)
data = X.rvs(3000)

def likelihood(params, data):
    c, loc, scale = params
    # Mind the minus sign for minimization
    return - stats.loglaplace.logpdf(data, c=c, loc=loc, scale=scale).sum()

p0 = [1., -1., 10.]
results = optimize.minimize(likelihood, p0, args=(data,))
#       fun: 11834.328446172953
#  hess_inv: array([[ 3.98302416e-04, -4.38626807e-06, -5.10104269e-04],
#        [-4.38626807e-06,  8.95197993e-06,  2.10634948e-05],
#        [-5.10104269e-04,  2.10634948e-05,  2.66869796e-02]])
#       jac: array([0., 0., 0.])
#  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
#     nfev: 116
#      nit: 15
#     njev: 27
#   status: 0
#  success: True
#        x: array([ 1.07636068, -0.04651799, 10.13396896])
```

With your data it gives:

```
original_data = np.array([0.916666, 1, 3.3, 3.38333, 3.68333, 4.16667, 4.2, 6.08333, 6.61667, 7.03333, 7.5, 7.85, 8.15, 9.08333, 9.35, 10.0833, 10.1833, 10.4333, 11.2833, 14.2, 16.5333, 20.0333, 23.8333, 30.35, 30.5167, 32.4667, 37.1, 40.8167, 45.6, 52, 70.0667, 70.5333, 85.2333, 130.967])

 #      fun: 143.3183272859989
 # hess_inv: array([[ 0.06063633, -0.27002167, -0.01566576],
 #       [-0.27002167,  2.81922376,  0.21352969],
 #       [-0.01566576,  0.21352969,  0.77303566]])
 #     jac: array([ 0.73000717, -1.26998901, -0.43971252])
 #  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
 #     nfev: 52
 #      nit: 2
 #     njev: 11
 #   status: 2
 #  success: False
 #        x: array([ 1.12952744, -0.4226847 , 10.2751086 ])
```

Where we can confirm the gradient has not been cancelled hence the warning message.

Comment: This could be improved by addressing the underlying problem, which is that there are no bounds on the decision variables.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: the best way to fit log-Laplace is usually to take the log of the data, fit to the Laplace distribution using the analytical formulas, and transform the parameters back to those of log-Laplace, but if we're interested in fixing the existing code or want the MLE of the location...*

Assuming the sign of the LLF is fixed, it can converge with your original data if you include appropriate bounds on the decision variables. Otherwise, the optimizer can try negative values of the shape and scale, which aren't in the domain, or it can make the location greater than the minimum value in your data, which puts some of the data outside of the distribution's support. This results in NaNs or INFs that give the optimization trouble.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats, optimize

data = [0.916666, 1.0, 3.3, 3.38333, 3.68333, 4.16667, 4.2, 6.08333, 6.61667, 
        7.03333, 7.5, 7.85, 8.15, 9.08333, 9.35, 10.0833, 10.1833, 10.4333, 
        11.2833, 14.2, 16.5333, 20.0333, 23.8333, 30.35, 30.5167, 32.4667, 
        37.1, 40.8167, 45.6, 52.0, 70.0667, 70.5333, 85.2333, 130.967]

def likelihood(params):
    return -stats.loglaplace(*params).logpdf(data).sum()

p0 = (1, 0, 10)
eps = 1e-15  # increase this if you still run into trouble 
bounds=[(eps, np.inf), (-np.inf, np.min(data)-eps), (eps, np.inf)]
results = optimize.minimize(likelihood, p0, bounds=bounds)
results

#  message: CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F_<=_FACTR*EPSMCH
#  success: True
#   status: 0
#      fun: 129.58932476489178
#        x: [ 4.767e-01  9.167e-01  1.016e+01]
#      nit: 11
#      jac: [ 2.565e-02 -8.435e+08  9.386e-02]
#     nfev: 80
#     njev: 20
# hess_inv: <3x3 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
```